What is the diagonal argument in this case?
In BG, the authors in the proof of Lemma 11 (page 22), write: "By definition of $\bar{\mathcal{X}}$ of (sic) there exists $\tilde{\mu}_n\rightarrow \mu$ weakly on $\mathfrak{G}\times\mathcal{L}_w$.  $(\text{reg}_{t:x,\varepsilon})_\ast\tilde{\mu}_{n}\rightarrow (\text{reg}_{t:x,\varepsilon})_\ast{\mu}$ on $\mathfrak{G}\times\mathcal{L}$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, and since
$(\text{reg}_{t:x,\varepsilon})_\ast{\mu}\rightarrow \mu$ weakly on $\mathfrak{G}\times\mathcal{L}$ as $\varepsilon\rightarrow 0$, we obtain
the statement by taking a diagonal sequence." Here the statement to be proven is that there exists a sequence $(\mu_n)_n$ such that $\mu_n \rightarrow \mu$ in norm.
Can someone please spell out the diagonal argument here where we have a sequence whose regularisation converges in the norm to a sequence that converges weakly to the required object, it is not clear to me. Thanks.
Edit: Please find below definitions of the objects above as per lulu's comment. 
$\mathfrak{G}$ here essentially a Banach space of vectors of (certain functionals) of Wicks Products, each of whose entries is a martingale. $\mathcal{L}$ here is the Banach space $L^2([0,\infty);W^{-1/2-\kappa,3})$, and $\mathcal{L}_w$ is the same equipped with the weak topology. $\mathbb{L}_a$ is the set of predictable processes in $\mathcal{L}$.

Questions here should be reasonably self contained.  We should not need to study external links in order to understand the basic terms of a question.

I did not think that the exact definitions were relevant to what the authors refer to a "diagonal argument" but I will add the details now.

I'm guessing taking $ (\operatorname{reg}{t,x,\varepsilon_n})\star \tilde{\mu}_n $ is what you want to do, for some sequence $(\varepsilon_n)_n$ converging to $0$, which you make depend on $n$ so you take the limit jointly in both these parameters. I don't know how you'd get strong convergence, but I think that's the idea.

I agree, but like you I don't see how we are getting strong convergence.
